# iOS unhide view with left to right animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, storyboard

I added view in storyboard it is hidden initially.
I unhide view on button click as following:

```
_myView.hidden=NO;
```

I want to unhide this view with left to right animation storyboard?
how i can set animation to this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: this view come from left to right

Comment: @Divyesh try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115854/animating-hide-show

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357005/how-to-move-the-uiview-from-left-to-right-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

/*===VIEW ANIMATIONS====*/

```
class func viewSlideInFromRightToLeft(views: UIView) {
        var transition: CATransition? = nil
        transition = CATransition()
        transition!.duration = 0.5
        transition!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition!.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition!.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        transition!.delegate = self
        views.layer.addAnimation(transition!, forKey: nil)
    }
   class func viewSlideInFromLeftToRight(views: UIView) {
        var transition: CATransition? = nil
        transition = CATransition()
        transition!.duration = 0.5
        transition!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition!.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition!.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        transition!.delegate = self
        views.layer.addAnimation(transition!, forKey: nil)
    }
   class func viewSlideInFromTopToBottom(views: UIView) {
        var transition: CATransition? = nil
        transition = CATransition()
        transition!.duration = 0.5
        transition!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition!.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition!.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
        transition!.delegate = self
        views.layer.addAnimation(transition!, forKey: nil)
    }
   class func viewSlideInFromBottomToTop(views: UIView) {
        var transition: CATransition? = nil
        transition = CATransition()
        transition!.duration = 0.5
        transition!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition!.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition!.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
        transition!.delegate = self
        views.layer.addAnimation(transition!, forKey: nil)
    }



 viewName.hidden=false 
self.viewSlideInFromLeftToRight(viewName)
```

Comment: Create one empty swift file and add above code file you can use this with objective-c like regular helper class

Comment: Still if you face any problem than feel free to ask i will add one project on Github :)