# Creating an overlay view that describes the app usage in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, overlay

I am a beginner in iOS objective C. I want to know if there is a way to create an overlay view for first time user of the app.

For example, Suppose there is an image and if the user swipes to rigth it is, "like" and if swiped left it is "dislike". Before the user uses the app, I want the user to know what right swipe an d left swipe stands for. How do I do this only to the "first time users" immediately after login?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is too broad and you need to narrow it down to a specific issue you might be having. Yes, you can do what you're describing, and there are a lot of methods to accomplish that, but you really ought to try and do something first before asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple **UIViews** to show your features (like say swiping feature). You need to add **Animation** to that UIViews to indicate your features of app.

Go through following examples;

[Example 1](http://sledgedev.com/uiview-animations-with-objective-c-for-ios/)

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357005/how-to-move-the-uiview-from-left-to-right-and-vice-versa)

**OR**

You can also use available Page controls to achieve this as follows;

[Example 1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/charpagecontrol)

[Example 2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/parallaxcarousel)

[Example 2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagedflowview)

Hope this will help.